# Would a self signed ssl cert significantly slow down ajax requests?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, ajax

I have a site with a live scoring page that updates via ajax while games are going on.  It was working fine when the site was running on http.

We installed an ssl an its either self signed or misconfigured, but now the live scoring page ajax requests are running super slow and freezing users screens.

I actually had to switch my curl requests on my crons to curl -k after the ssl was installed so I'm wondering if the ssl itself could be causing the ajax requests to run sooo slow.  I realize https is slower than http but should it really be this noticeable?

Comment: No, but it'll probably prevent them entirely on some browsers due to security settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A self-signed certificate won't be any slower than a certificate signed by a trusted CA (it may even be faster depending on the length of the trust chain and whether OCSP is in use). If you haven't tested with a properly signed certificate then it's probably just HTTPS vs HTTP.

Check the CPU usage on your server, and whether the browsers are maintaining persistent connections.

Comment: +1. If you move all ajax to SSL that may simply kill the server. SSL is not exactly zero overhead. Depending how cheap you are hardware wise and the reserves you had - ouch.

Comment: ya, its looking like its just the https vs http.  I just optimized a bunch of https requests into one and things are running a great deal smoother.